# Plotting CDF and sample distribution together in Python Plot

Tags: python, distribution, cdf

I am quite new to Python and still learning. I have time series attribute and I'd like to plot the CDF curve and sample distribution together in the chart like below. Which Python library I should be looking at using to create similar chart. Any sample code examples would be quite helpful. Thanks.

Dataset schema is like below:

Name - Date - Count

A1 - 1 Jan 23 - 20000

B1 - 1 Jan 23 - 9000

A1 - 2 Jan 23 - 2000

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mm9wl.png)